# Raspberry pi 2 B + and DS18B20

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, ds18b20

I'm new in Raspberry... I have a problem, I'm trying to connect a DS18B20 temperature sensor to a Raspberry but I can't see anything start with `28-...` in `/sys/bus/w1/devices`

I've run

```
sudo modprobe w1-gpio; sudo modprobe w1-therm
```

[image: wiring]

[image: xterm screenshot]

I have this in my `/boot/config.txt`

```
__dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup,gpiopin=4__
```

If I run the example from [More than 10 DS18S20](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=637971&sid=51b21df2cd3ca670c45a01f6536ea08b#p637971) I get this:

> *** Error Unable to detect Logic level 1. No pull-up ?

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.